# Is this an A-series or a T-series light bulb?

Tags: lighting

The first of 3 bulbs in a new-to-us bathroom fixture has burnt out. I (my wife) would like to replace it with the same shape, but unfortunately the label had worn off -- all we can make out is "60" (watts, presumably). Anyone recognize it? I'm in the US. Have tried google image searching as well as tineye.com; the closest I've seen is an a-series-shaped tubular (t-series) bulb, but I'm striking out with local hardware stores.

Updated (based on finding the [Kirby Risk](https://www.kirbyrisk.com/index.jsp?path=AboutLightBulbs) site) - the width at the cylindrical part is about 2 1/8", making it an XXX-17 (or -18 if I'm mis-measuring).

[image: light bulb - side view]

[image: light bulb-top view]

Comment: That looks like some sort of specialty decorator bulb shape.  The number after the type designator is simply the width of the bulb - hard to judge scale, but I'd guess it's and A19.  Knowing the series likely won't help much in matching the *shape* though.  Have you considered replacing all 3 bulbs?

Comment: "replacing all 3" was my first plan, until my better half asked for the same shape ... if someone can find a link for some $20 bulbs from Madagascar, maybe we can return to 'Plan A' :)

Comment: @Comintern, that's not any kind of decorator lamp. It's simply Phillips version of an A-lamp from years ago.

Comment: If you have a good hardware store around, just take it there and tell them you need a replacement. They'll know exactly what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an older style Philips Halogena bulb meant to replace the typical incandescent bulb.  The lamp is a quartz halogen tube enclosed in a glass envelope that resembles an older style light bulb.  The 70 watt actual / 100 watt equivalent spec sheet for this style bulb can be seen here:

http://www.usa.philips.com/c-p/046677209698/halogena-energy-saver-household/specifications

In this case you have a 43 actual / 60 equivalent.  "A19" and "T60" are essentially the same thing.  "A" designates the original light bulb shape and "19" designates the diameter in eighths of an inch (bulb shape, 2.375" diameter).  "T" designates tubular shape, but unlike florescent tubes where the number indicates eighths of an inch, in this case the number is in millimeters.  "60" in indicates 2.36" diameter.  For all intents the two are interchangeable.

In the most recent version of this 60 watt halogen, Philips changed the glass envelope from metric "T60" to the english "A19":

http://www.homedepot.com/p/Philips-EcoVantage-60-Watt-Halogen-A19-Soft-White-Dimmable-Light-Bulb-4-Pack-426031/203637006

Comment: This is not just a halogen or Halogena lamp. Phillips had used this shape for years for it's A-lamps.